# From Last Friday 2 PM. Excel Formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have a big formula that counts from Last Friday 2 PM until next Friday 2 PM (+7).
I put the Date part in another cell (to facilitate view).
The below formula works ok, Except IF now is Friday > 2 PM until end of that day.
Any calculations on this period will not take effect until Tomorrow (Saturday)
I need to refine the formula to check if now is Friday +2.01 PM, to count from this time.
In addition, if not, use existing formula.

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+1)+TIME(14,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the below formula , and it works:

```
=IF(AND(NOW()>TODAY()+TIME(14,0,0),WEEKDAY(TODAY())=6),TODAY()+TIME(14,0,0),(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+1))+TIME(14,0,0))
```